# Populating table from array only shows up on the first cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am having a problem populating a tableview in the next segue. Basically I am sending all the strings in one combined string then populating an array with it. From that array I am populating the table. The problem is this shows up only in the very first cell. I would like for each entry that has a comma to break to the next cell. Here is the code for the first ViewControler.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet    UITableView     *myTableView;
NSMutableArray  *locationArray;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet  UITableView     *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain)           NSMutableArray  *locationArray;

- (void) populateLocationArray;
@end
```

Here is the ViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 NSLog(@"Row Selected %i",indexPath.row);



if (indexPath.section==0) {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:nil];

}

}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"PrepareForSegueCalled");
LocationItems *destination = [segue destinationViewController];

//If statement for city pressed
destination.titleOfView = @"Boston";

NSArray *myStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third", @"fourth", @"fifth", nil];
destination.arrayToBePopulatedString = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
// destination.arrayToBePopulatedString = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
   // [destination.populationArray addObjectsFromArray:myStrings];
}
```

The controller called LocationItems is the view with the table I would like to populate. Here is LocationItems.h

```
@interface LocationItems : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet    UITableView     *locationTableView;
NSString *titleOfView;
NSString *arrayToBePopulatedString;
NSMutableArray *populationArray;

NSMutableArray *bostonArray;
}

- (void) populateArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *locationTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *titleOfView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *arrayToBePopulatedString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *populationArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bostonArray;

@end
```

And finally the LocationItems.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
bostonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self populateArray];


//********************************************************
//If string = boston load some array containing the cities.

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void) populateArray {

[bostonArray addObject:arrayToBePopulatedString];
//[bostonArray addObject:populationArray];
//[bostonArray addObject:@"Boston"];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:1]; 
    //[[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:

     }

// Configure the cell.
[cell.textLabel setText:[bostonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
}

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [bostonArray.self count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSLog(@"Row Selected %i",indexPath.row);




}
```

I apologize in advance for such a long question but believe it necessary to fully explain my problem. I would simply like each cell to have a different word (First, second, third, ect). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your arrayToBePopulatedString look like?  Use NSLog in ViewDidLoad in LocationItems.m

Comment: That is used under the populateArray method. [bostonArray addObject:arrayToBePopulatedString];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand what you mean by:

> I am sending all the strings in one combined string then populating an
>   array with it.

Do you mean that you wish to split the string that contains all substrings and make an array out of it?

From what I get from your code, you take the concatenated string, where all values are separated by spaces and you store it as the first element of an array:

```
destination.arrayToBePopulatedString = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
...
[bostonArray addObject:arrayToBePopulatedString];
```

This simply adds the complete string in the array.

If you want to split the concatenated string back into an array, you should probably use something like

```
bostonArray = [[destination.arrayToBePopulatedString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "] retain];
```

Then you no longer need to allocate an array in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hello, this still leaves all of the words in the first cell.

Comment: Hello, sorry about the previous comment. I had the code in the wrong location. This worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. I just noticed that I was missing a retain, as componentsSeparatedByString returns an autoreleased object. bostonArray becomes a bad reference as soon as it is autoreleased, which will lead to random crashes when you try to access it. I have updated the answer to fix this.

Comment: When changing to retain I am getting an "retain is unavaliable" error. The build fails.

Comment: Also when going back to what you have it does work but I get the warning "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NAMutableArray *_strong' from 'NSArray".

Comment: If you are using ARC, you can ignore the retain (sorry for the confusion). Also, you are right, this method returns an immutable NSArray, not a NSMutableArray. If you do not need to modify the array after (from what I understood from your code, you no longer modify it), you can change the type from NSMutableArray* to NSArray*. If you want to keep it mutable, you are going to need to use the mutableCopy method when assigning the array to bostonArray.

Comment: I do need to keep it mutable as that is how I provide the strings from ViewController.h in prepareForSegue to the LocationItems.m populateArray method. Could you please clarify the mutableCopy? Im wanting to send the strings based on what city is chosen. So different info will be sent to this second screen (LocationItems) depending on what the user selects in the previous table.

Comment: From the code that you pasted, you do not seem to be modifying the array. Be careful, this array is used as the data source for your table view. If you modify it and the table view reloads, or you eventually want to use it when the user touches the cell, you may have issues. That being said, if you still want to make a mutableArray from the string instead of a NSArray, you will simply do  something like: bostonArray = [[destination.arrayToBePopulatedString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "] mutableCopy];

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I only see the info being changed once and thats from the first screen depending on what they send. Under prepareForSegue I get an error when I put this code so I have been putting what you have sent under the viewDidLoad of the LocationItems.m class. Im pretty sure this is the wrong thing to do but the main error I get is that it does not know what bostonArray is on the ViewController.m class even though LocationItems is imported. Any advice for this situation?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that if I do not put this code in the viewDidLoad of the LocationItems.m class the table does not populate.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [bostonArray.self count]; // typo here? [self.bostonArray count]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to change `bostonArray addObject` to `bostonArray addObjectsFromArray`.

Using addObject causes the entire array to be added to the first element of bostonArray.

Comment: In his case, arrayToBePopulatedString is an NSString. He converted the original array in a single NSString, so it adds the entire string as the first element of an empty array.

Comment: When doing that with the arrayToBePopulatedString there is a crash as the string is not an array. I should explain why im going through all this trouble to populate the table. Since there will be multiple cities, instead of having a static, pre defined view, I am hoping for a dynamic table that will populate based on the city selected by the user.